# How to implement RFID features in our Android Application?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

I want to develop an android app using android 4.0 API level, in my application I want to implement RFID features can anyone give me the idea or any code snippet regarding RFID feature implementation in android application.

Thanks to All.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at Nordic Id STIX uhf rfid reader.You can connect it to your phone using USB Ports.
They will provide you SDK for Application development.
Link : http://www.nordicid.com/eng/products/?group=7

Answer (score 2):

You can develop Android application using `NFC` (RFID-like technology). More about NFC API here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try to get Professional Android Sensor programing e-book it explains how to implement lots of sensors including RFID, geolocation and lots of other stuff that might be helpfull.

Hope it helped.